Any work-around to keep using Microsoft Graph SDK for Android
For accessing OneDrive in an Android App build with Android Studio I have used the Microsoft Graph SDK for Android https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-android
and MSA Auth library for Android
https://github.com/OfficeDev/msa-auth-for-android
for many years. All of a sudden this no longer works and I can not even re-build my app: Gradle sync is OK, but when building the project, Download Info lists these errors:
Failed  https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/microsoft/services/msa/msa-auth/maven-metadata.xml
Failed  https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/microsoft/graph/msgraph-sdk-android/maven-metadata.xml

I am aware these both are deprecated libaries, but I see no mention why suddenly the maven-metadata.xml is no longer available causing the build to fail completely.
I tried cleaning the project, setting Gradle to offline mode but both to no avail.
Anyone else seeing this too and has a work-around, even temporarily this would at least get me some time to move to the recommended generic ms-graph Java library
TIA,

Given that these libraries are no longer maintained and which may lead to the issues you're experiencing, I would advise that you switch to the new library since it will also guarantee the latest features and updates including security updates.
While switching to a new library can be time-consuming, we recommend moving to the Microsoft Graph Java SDK as this is the most reliable solution to your problem.
The MS Graph Java SDK is functionally equivalent to the Android SDK -works across all standard Java platforms and is kept up to date and guaranteed to be maintained by Microsoft.

Hi,  I have started investigating using the MS Graph Java SDK as that indeed seems the way to go, but ran into the problem of how to set that up with the MSAL Authorization library for Android. I posted this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78919114/how-to-connect-msal-authentication-for-android-with-graph-sdk-for-java-version-6     would you by chance have a clue how to connect these?
